# Couldn't add PHP 7.4 to Webmin/Virtualmin

Tags: linux, centos, php, webmin, virtualmin

I followed [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370480/linux-add-php-7-4-to-webmin-virtualmin) which actually referred to [this](https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/multiplephp/#Installing_PHP_74_andor_80_on_CentOS_7) but after I did the installation for my CentOS 7 and went to System Settings -> Re-Check Config at VirtualMin, I see the same PHP versions I already have as shown below.

```
The following PHP versions are available : 5.4.16 (/bin/php-cgi), 7.0.27 (/opt/rh/rh-php70/root/usr/bin/php-cgi), 7.1.30 (/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/bin/php-cgi), 5.4 (mod_php)

The following PHP-FPM versions are available on this system : 5.4.16 (php-fpm) 7.0.27 (rh-php70-php-fpm) 7.1.30 (rh-php71-php-fpm)
```

No PHP 7.4 is listed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you find a solution?